# Assign class variables without repeating code

Tags: python, oop, data-science

So I learned to code this year ad started working on my first big project. I am collecting data from quiverquant to loop through the data and find the highest numbers, most bought tickers, etc. I built the class to pull data, but I cant figure out how to save each data pull to a class variable with out repeating much code.

Here is what I came up with so far!
As you can see data will just be appended with data from each sector and I will have no way to work with individual data sets. I could still get this moving by compiling all data and iterating through it. I have added more class variables, just need to figure out how to append each accordingly.

````
# I am going to apply OOP to this, for good OOP practice.
# Author: @yellinggs

import json
import requests

#Returns the most recent transactions by U.S. Representatives
house = "https://api.quiverquant.com/beta/live/housetrading"
#Returns the most recent transactions by members of U.S. Congress
congress = "https://api.quiverquant.com/beta/live/congresstrading"
#Returns all of the stock transactions by U.S. Senators involving the given ticker
senate = "https://api.quiverquant.com/beta/live/senatetrading"
#Returns the 500 most recently announced contracts across all companies
contracts = "https://api.quiverquant.com/beta/live/govcontractsall"
#Returns last quarter's government contract amounts for all companies
quarterly_contracts = "https://api.quiverquant.com/beta/live/govcontracts"
#Returns the most recent lobbying spending instances across all companies.
corp_lobbying = "https://api.quiverquant.com/beta/live/lobbying"
#Returns yesterday's off-exchange activity across all companies.
off_exchange = "https://api.quiverquant.com/beta/live/offexchange"
#Returns all of the stock transactions by members of U.S. Congress involving the given ticker
congress_ticker = "https://api.quiverquant.com/beta/historical/congresstrading/{ticker}"

class GetData():
    data = []
    house_data = []
    congress_data = []
    senate_data = []
    contracts_data = []
    quarterly_contracts_data = []
    corp_lobbying_data = []
    off_exchange_data = []
    congress_ticker_data = []
    def __init__(self, sector):
        self.data = GetData.data
        self.sector = sector 

    def get_data(self): 
        url = self.sector
        headers = {'accept': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRFToken': 'TyTJwjuEC7VV7mOqZ622haRaaUr0x0Ng4nrwSRFKQs7vdoBcJlK9qjAS69ghzhFu',
        'Authorization': 'Token not today stackoverflow :D'}
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers) 
        GetData.data.append(json.loads(r.content))
        print('Pulled data from {}'.format(url))
    
    def print_data(self):
        try:
            GetData.get_data(self)
            print(GetData.piped_data)
        except Exception:
            print('No data to show!!!!')

house_info = GetData(house)
congress_info = GetData(congress)
senate_info = GetData(senate)
congress_info.get_data()
#house_info.get_data()
#senate_info.print_data()```
````

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things.  You are thinking too literally and you need to think how to make this more dynamic.  Remember simpler is better.

```
import json
import requests

# Returns the most recent transactions by U.S. Representatives
routes = {
    'house' : "https://api.quiverquant.com/beta/live/housetrading",
    # Returns the most recent transactions by members of U.S. Congress
    'congress' : "https://api.quiverquant.com/beta/live/congresstrading",
    # Returns all of the stock transactions by U.S. Senators involving the given ticker
    'senate' : "https://api.quiverquant.com/beta/live/senatetrading",
    # Returns the 500 most recently announced contracts across all companies
    'contracts' : "https://api.quiverquant.com/beta/live/govcontractsall",
    # Returns last quarter's government contract amounts for all companies
    'quarterly_contracts' : "https://api.quiverquant.com/beta/live/govcontracts",
    # Returns the most recent lobbying spending instances across all companies.
    'corp_lobbying' : "https://api.quiverquant.com/beta/live/lobbying",
    # Returns yesterday's off-exchange activity across all companies.
    'off_exchange' : "https://api.quiverquant.com/beta/live/offexchange",
    # Returns all of the stock transactions by members of U.S. Congress involving the given ticker
    'congress_ticker' : "https://api.quiverquant.com/beta/historical/congresstrading/{ticker}"
          }

cache = []

class GetData():

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
        self.sector = None
        self.url = None

    def get(self, sector):
        global cache
        self.sector = sector
        self.url = routes[sector]
        headers = {'accept': 'application/json',
                   'X-CSRFToken': 'TyTJwjuEC7VV7mOqZ622haRaaUr0x0Ng4nrwSRFKQs7vdoBcJlK9qjAS69ghzhFu',
                   'Authorization': 'Token not today stackoverflow :D'}
        r = requests.get(self.url, headers=headers)
        result = json.loads(r.content)
        if result:
            self.data.append(result)
            if result not in cache: #cut down on duplicates
                cache.append(result)
        return self.data
    
x = GetData()
house_info = x.get('house')
congress_info = x.get('congress')
senate_info = x.get('senate')
print(congress_info)
print(cache)
```

**Why a dict for routes**

Using a dict gives you more flexibility as you build out your app.  It makes adding routes easy and seemless, and also allows you to add routes on the fly via any datasource.  You really should use dicts instead of a litany of variables.

Comment: when I read OP's post I also thought, why is he calling the class inside of its own functions like `GetData.data.append(json.loads(r.content))` or `GetData.get_data(self)` instead of `self.data`and `self.get_data` but I wasn't sure. is this way of writing code wrong or is it just not utilising the advantage of class/function structure ?

Comment: You really shouldn't call the class from within the same class unless you were instantiating a new instance (like containerizing a data structure).  I suspect this is just a healthy dose of over engineering common in people learning.  Which is why I like answering these questions.

Comment: I think this can be simplified further. There doesn't seem to be any purpose to `GetData.__init__` looking up the URL in an external `dict`, as opposed to simply receiving the URL as an argument along with the sector.

Comment: (Also, why update a cache if `get_data` doesn't look there before making an HTTP request?)

Comment: You might want to know the sector down the road.  You should never build just to solve the current problem, you should build to solve all future problems.  And all calls to get data fetch, so I check to see if it exists in cache if not I update.  This is appropriate.

Comment: Wow this is super helpful, I think you're right about overthinking it. I thought about reading through some code on GitHub so learn better practices and styles. This was my first attempt, I can only go up from here. Thanks!

Comment: I made it better after actually looking at it.